# Find $h$ that will put a vector in a given span

Tags: linear-algebra

> For what values of $h$ is the vector $[8h,h^2,8]$ in $S=\operatorname{span}([-2,0,4],[5,-2,2])$?

So I made the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-2&5&8h\\
0&-2&h^2\\
4&2&8\end{bmatrix}$$
Looking at the second row, $h^2 = -2$. Doesn't this make the matrix inconsistent since there will be no real solutions to this equation?

Comment: The phrase, "make a vector a span of a set" makes no sense. Please edit your question into something sensible. Also, what does $h^2-2$ have to do with $h^2=-2$?

Comment: edited already sir

Comment: Good. But I don't know what you mean by, "Looking at the second row, $h^2=-2$." That would make sense if you were trying to decide whether $(8h,h^2,8)$ could ever equal $(5,-2,2)$, but that's not what the question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

All vectors in $S$ are of the form
$$(-2a+5b,-2b,4a+2b),\ a,b\in\Bbb R$$
For $(8h,h^2,8)$ to be in $S$ there must be a solution to the following system of equations:
$$8h=-2a+5b\tag1$$
$$h^2=-2b\tag2$$
$$8=4a+2b\tag3$$
Adding $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get
$$h^2+8=4a$$
$$\frac12(h^2+8)=2a\tag4$$
Adding $(1)$ and $(4)$ we get
$$8h+\frac12(h^2+8)=5b$$
$$16h+h^2+8=10b$$
By adding 5 times $(2)$ to this last equation we get a quadratic in $h$ only:
$$16h+h^2+8+5h^2=0$$
$$6h^2+16h+8=0$$
$$3h^2+8h+4=0$$
$$3(h+2)\left(h+\frac23\right)=0$$
Finally, we obtain that the values of $h$ for which $(8h,h^2,8)$ lies in the given span are $h=-2$ and $h=-\frac23$.